# Agregar valores faltantes a cadena de caracteres

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Me surge la siguiente interrogante con un problema en una consulta.

Tengo el campo **"NumAtCard"** en mi tabla el cual puede tener de 3 a 5 caracteres.

Ejemplifico: Facturas-3512, Notas de crédito-451, Notas de Débito-54215

Mi problema radica que esos valores tienen que ser de 8 caracteres por cuestiones legales en la entrega de un reporte a hacienda dichos valores que se agregarian serian 0 a la izquierda si el valor es una factura 3512 tendria que ser 00003512.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de agregar esos 0 a la izquierda contando la cadena de **"NumAtCard"** y si es menor que 8 agregar los caracteres faltantes como 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrias hacer uso de un Format

```
    DECLARE @Dato VARCHAR(8)='123'
    DECLARE @Dato2 VARCHAR(8)='1234566'

    SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@Dato AS INT),'D8');
    SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@Dato2 AS INT),'D8');
```

Esto acompleta segun lo que te falte en este caso le mando 123 y el me pinta las 5 ceros que hacen falto espero te sirva y si no ahora vemos que podemos hacer.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000000' + NumAtCard, 8);
```

Con lo que concatenas 8 ceros al valor que tengas en tu campo y luego siempre te quedas los 8 de más a la derecha.

Comment: El detalle con esto es que recorta los valores a la derecha si, pero no toma en cuenta los 0 a la izquiera si el valor esta 000000002153 y le corto 8 tomara 2153 no 00002153 ademas la sintaxis de esto es RIGHT(EXP1, INT).

Comment: @Luis, si que funciona, te paso el [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/53491/0)

Comment: Una variante cuando el campo es numérico es `RIGHT(100000000 + NumAtCard, 8)`